# Highlight C# code in CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror

I'm using **CodeMirror 5.1**. [This article](http://codemirror.net/1/contrib/csharp/) shows C# syntax highlighting, but apparently addresses an outdated version of CodeMirror.

**Question:** How do you achieve true **C#** highlighting with CodeMirror (and I don't mean the "clike" parser) ?

Note, that this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837538/codemirror-c-sharp-highlighting) question. The solution there is "clike", which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Either this question is a duplicate of the one linked (which I think it is, even if you don't like the answer), or it's off topic because it asks us to find a tool or resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `text/x-csharp` MIME type defined by the clike mode is a C#-specific mode. If that's not what you are looking for, it would have helped to at least say what your problem with it is.

Comment: The problem is that c-like is nothing like C#. It merely highlights numbers. Where do I define this MIME type?

Comment: Great! Now that looks more line C#. It's not the same colors, but close enough. Thanks :)